# java - split string using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I need to split a string where there's a comma, but it depends where the comma is placed.

As an example

consider the following:

```
C=75,user_is_active(A,B),user_is_using_app(A,B),D=78
```

I'd like the `String.split()` function to separate them like this:

```
C=75 

user_is_active(A,B) 

user_using_app(A,B)

D=78
```

I can only think of one thing but I'm not sure how it'd be expressed in regex.

The characters/words within the brackets are always capital. In other words, there won't be a situation where I will have `user_is_active(a,b)`.

Is there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't have more than one level of parentheses, you could do a split on a comma that isn't followed by a closing `)` before an opening `(`:

```
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split(
    "(?x),   # Verbose regex: Match a comma\n" +
    "(?!     # unless it's followed by...\n" +
    " [^(]*  # any number of characters except (\n" +
    " \\)    # and a )\n" +
    ")       # end of lookahead assertion");
```

Your proposed rule would translate as

```
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split(
    "(?x),        # Verbose regex: Match a comma\n" +
    "(?<!\\p{Lu}) # unless it's preceded by an uppercase letter\n" +
    "(?!\\p{Lu})  # or followed by an uppercase letter");
```

but then you would miss a split in a text like

```
Org=NASA,Craft=Shuttle
```

Comment: this works prefect! I dont think I will have more than one level parentheses! thanks! :D

Comment: +1 And if the `(A,B)` construct will only ever have one comma inside, you can speed this up dramatically by adding a comma to the `[^(]*` expression i.e. `[^(,]*`.

Comment: in my case I could have something(A,B,C) so it wouldn't apply but it's good to know! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

consider using a **parser generator** for parsing this kind of query. E.g: [javacc](http://javacc.java.net/) or [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you need more than one level of parentheses, you can create a little string parser for parsing the string character by character.