# Java Regex Matcher works, but String.split() doesn't

Tags: java, regex

I am looking to use a one line String.split() to pull out the 'name' in a query I am writting..

The Pattern + Matcher works like expected, but I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why String.split() doesn't return a match!

```
public static void main(String[] asdf)
{
    final String queryText = "id <equals> `1` <AND> name <equals> `some name`";
    final String regex = "^(.*name <equals> `)([\\S\\s]*)(`.*)$";

    System.out.println("Splitting...");
    final String[] split = queryText.split(regex);
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(split[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Matching...");
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(queryText);

    if (matcher.find())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Prints the output

```
Splitting...
Matching...
id <equals> `1` <AND> name <equals> `
some name
`
```

Comment: Your match covers the entire string. Hence, if you `split` by the match, the two resulting strings are empty. And trailing empty strings are omitted by default. Use the [overload with an integer argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)) and supply a negative integer to get the empty strings, if that is what you want. In Java, `split` does not return the matched groups in addition to the splits (as it works in some other languages).

Comment: The regex `[\\S\\s]` is insane - it means "any character that is a whitespace or not a whitespace. It's the same as `.`

Comment: Thanks for the input Bohemian.. I had started with `.` and forgot to put it back.

Comment: @Bohemian only in combination with the dotall modifier.

Comment: @m.buettner fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex matches the whole string. Thus, when splitting, the whole string gets removed. It is exactly the same as `"a".split("a")`, which returns an empty array.

What you could use instead is:

```java
queryText.replaceAll(".*name <equals> `([^`]+)`.*", "$1")
```

which returns `some name`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex expression covers all the string. Try to remove "^" and "$".
Split method wants the expressions to remove not the expressions that must be found to detect a particular substring.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the regex

```
((?<=`)[^`]*(?=`$))
```

as this gives you the result "*some name*" from

```
id <equals> `1` <AND> name <equals> `some name`
```

or if the "*some name*" does not Always appears at the end you can use

```
((?<=name <equals> `)[^`]*(?=`))
```

with the same result

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the input.  [m.buettner] was correct.  I was merely misunderstanding what `String.split()` is supposed to do.  Per the Java documentation..

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

This isn't what I wanted.  I will merely create a util method with my Pattern + Matcher.

Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Your regex variable is not properly formed for the String split() method... Try breaking the regex as shown in the answer of this thread...

[java - split string using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363164/java-split-string-using-regular-expression)